# How to export to a pre-named folder in Lightroom

Tags: lightroom

I would like to configure an export setting in Lightroom so that it writes to a folder of the same name as the original folder, but in a different location (without re-typing the name  of the folder every time of course). For example

- the original folder is "/photos/2013-02-01 some event"
- I want the target folder to be "/exports/2013-02-01 some event"

AFAIK, export lets one either

- export in a subfolder of the original folder, with a fixed name (fixed relative to the export setting)
- or, name the export folder every time.

So, if this isn't directly possible in the settings of the export function, is it possible to do as an extension / plugin? How hard is it to develop a simple Lightroom extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automatically exporting with the folder structure you want is not possible from the standard Lightroom Export dialog.

It is definitely possible to write a plugin to do this and if you have any previous programming experience it will be straightforward as the SDK includes several sample export plugins that can be used as a base for yours.

The Lightroom SDK is available from [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshoplightroom.html)

Comment: Thanks. The version of the SDK is numbered "4" and I use Lightroom 3.4; does the version of the SDK refer to the SDK itself, or to a version of Lightroom? Page 23 of the user manual that deals with LrSdkVersion and LrSdkMinimumVersion is not clear on this point...?

Comment: As far as I'm aware the SDK version does relate to the Lightroom version, but is backwards compatible with previous versions as long as you don't try to use features that are only available in a newer version (which can be found by checking the documentation in the API Reference folder in the SDK download). If the mismatch turns out to be a problem you can try [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshoplightroom/sdk/eula_lr3.html) link, which is to the Lightroom 3 SDK download.

Answer (score 4):

In fact there is already a plugin that does exactly that, called "Tree Mirror Export" and available here: http://www.newpproducts.com/?page_id=2877